# PHP Elastic Search - fetching all documents before executing search (to save time/performance)

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am currently using the following query in a php function `hitCount($keyword)`

```
  'query' => [
    'bool' => [
      'must' => [
        [
          'range' => [
            'date' => [
              'gte' => 'now-4w/d',
              'lt'  => 'now/d'
            ],
          ]
        ],
        [
          'match' => [
            'content' => $keyword
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

It allows me to go through a list of `keywords` and execute the query for each `keyword` - i basically want to know "how many times has a keyword been included in the last 4 weeks" - and it works perfectly fine for a handful of keywords. But as you can imagine as soon as I want to execute this function for a long array of keywords (100+) it starts to take a long time because it needs to fetch all documents first before it can look for my matching keyword.

now my question:

how can i make this query faster? can I first fetch all documents of the past 4 weeks ( the range date query) and THEN execute the match-keyword query?
Something like that:

```
$documentsToSearchIn = $client->get($prefetchParams);
$finalResponse = $client->search($matchParams, $documentsToSearchIn);
```

Comment: You should actually try to move the `range` clause inside `bool/filter` and only leave the `match` one inside `bool/must`. Any improvement?

Comment: @Val hey, thanks for the answer! I moved the range statement into bool/filter. can't tell a difference, sadly

Comment: Yeah, ES is clever enough to execute the range clause first, but just wanted to make sure first.

Comment: Then, the time the query now takes relates to how well your cluster is sized compared to the volume of data you have... Care to share some numbers?

Comment: @Val I've only got 6k entries so far, 4 shards and for roughly 25 keywords it takes about 8 seconds to finish all of them -just got into ES so I dont know too much

Comment: What about the specs of your cluster? how many nodes (I guess a single one), cpus, ram/heap, etc?

Comment: @Val Sorry for the late reply! Since I wanted to get the hit count anyway I just used ES's client->count($params) function which is way faster